# Using MAMP to install wordpress and getting blank page

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am using MAMP to install wordpress on localhost and receive a blank page

http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2

When I checking the error log

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.0.13\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 (C:\MAMP\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/MAMP/bin/apache -f C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Chad

Comment: Did you go to /wp-install/ before going to the /wp-admin/setup-config.php?

Comment: No, I did not. 

I since went and renamed the wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php. I opened wp-config.php and updated the database details.

I then went and loaded http://localhost:8888/mysite/wp-admin/install.php

and got this 

The requested URL /mysite/wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server.